# pre-built GUI for uploading .csv and adding data to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

Anyone know of a plugin out there that will help me bump a .csv file onto a mySQL database?  Was planning on building this from scratch myself but realized that all the code I need is probably already out there.  Detailed description of what I am trying to do can be found below.

I want to add a gui to my webpage that allows a user to select a .csv file from their local computer, upload that .csv file onto the server and add the data in the csv to a mySQL database table.  Also, it would be nice if there was validation in the code that confirmed that the structure of .csv data matched the mySQL table.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions on where I can find this or even where/how you think I should go about looking for it.  Doesn't necessarily need to be a standalone plugin.  If you know of a project on github that has this code in it that would be very helpful as well.

Thanks
Evan

Comment: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/ has some of the functionality you described. It has a lot of other features that you don't need, so the noise to signal ratio may be a bit high for what you are looking for.

Comment: http://www.group3solutions.com/blog/tips-on-phpmyadmin-csv-importing/ - phpmyadmin is on github: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

There is couple of prebuilt plugin on phpclassess :http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2917-PHP-Import-CSV-data-into-a-MySQL-database-table.html